Как проверить тип чата? Python - Aiogram 3.x
Я хочу, чтобы бот принимал фото/видео/текст только в личных сообщениях, но не понимаю как это сделать.
async def go(message: Message):
    if F.chat_type == "private":
        with open('config.py', 'r') as f:
            a = f.readline()
        b = int(a)
        b += 1
        with open('config.py', 'w+') as f:
            f.write(str(b))


chat = message.chat
if chat.type == 'private':
#do something


Предыдущий ответ дан верно, однако добавлю:
Для того чтобы получить тип чата полученного сообщения, необходимо обратиться к
message.chat.type

Все типы чатов описаны в документации aiogram https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/enums/chat_type.html

SENDER = 'sender'
PRIVATE = 'private'
GROUP = 'group'
SUPERGROUP = 'supergroup'
CHANNEL = 'channel'

В вашем фрагменте кода нужно заменить условие на следующее:
if message.chat.type == "private":

